# Tashlumin for a woman who usually doesn't daven

Tags: tefilla, women

What is the halacha for a woman who usually doesn't daven since she is busy with her children but now has time to daven mincha and even time to daven a Tashlumin. Do we say that she should only daven mincha(since tashlumin applies only to a regualr davener) or she should daven a tashlumin since she is only patur because she is busy with the children?

Comment: How is this different from an Onein? What's "a regualr davener"?

Comment: Not an answer: I think you just answered your own question.

Comment: Since a woman follows the Rambam in this case she has satisfied her obligation of prayer in a sense so maybe she doesn't need to but on the other hand lechatchila she should follow the Ramban

Comment: @sam ??? I don't who you are responding, to but both [Rambam](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/2206.htm#10) and Ramban agree that Oseik BeMitzva exempts you from davening and that men and women have the same obligation regarding prayer.

Comment: My point was that the Rambam holds a woman fulfills her obligation with shevach hodah and bakasha ,where the Ramban is of the opinion that women need to daven what the Rabbann set forth

Comment: And the nafka mina would be if a woman is busy she has to fulfill the Rambams opinion at least,so do we say that she needs a tashlumin for the Rambans opinion or she is covered by the opinion of the Rambam,probably have to edit question

Comment: @sam What are you are talking about? Rambam says women are obligated in Shmone Esrei. I linked to it above. If someone is busy with a Mitzva (eg. raising children) then s/he is exempt even from the Torah obligation (if there is one) just like those carrying the dead to be buried. [Alternatively, someone who is busy with children is exempt from prayer due to inability to concentrate.](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21547&st=&pgnum=85) Either way we generally seem to paskin no tashlumin in those cases, I think.

Comment: It is hard to bring all the shittos in a comment but the Magen Avraham reads the Mechaber that a women is required only a short prayer per the Ramabam,even if you want to say that shmoneh esrei is required by both ,there is a difference since if one has time only to follow the Rambam idea of dorasia then maybe a tashlumin is not necessary, but the Ramban holds that tefilla is only a derabbanan from an asmachta.

Comment: @sam I see no reason at all to say that someone who fulfills the Doraysa requirement of Tefila is exempt from Tashlumin (ignoring gender issues; consider the case of someone who missed Mincha but did Bench that afternoon, or better someone who missed Mincha but did Daven Shachrit). Also that is not what the Magen Avraham said! He just said that "it's possible [according to the side that some Tefila is biblical] Chazal never enacted [fixed prayer] for women". He never ever ever says that he thinks any Rishonim (or the ShA) said that, bc none of them did. He's making up a hypothetical position.

Comment: For Sefardi women, Harav Bentzion Abba Shaul has a T'shuva for this exact question in his Sefer אור לציון